# Junit5 methods are not running in parallel

Tags: junit5

I am using Junit5 and have a bunch of test classes (approx 5) each having a few methods (approx 10). I want to run all of them in parallel i.e, in 50+ possible threads. I have done the following system parameters

```
-Djunit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true 
-Djunit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=concurrent 
-Djunit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default=concurrent
```

Inside my test class I also have the annotation `@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)` when I run this test I do observe that the tests are still only running in parallel at the class level and are not running in parallel at the method level.

How can I debug what I am doing wrong? Is there a way to get Junit5 to print some more diagnostic information about the parallelism?